# How can I scroll 2 div's horizontally in opposite directions with mousewheel?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I would like to know how I can scroll 2 different `div`'s in opposite directions with the mousewheel. I would like them to overlap (`z-index`) one on top of the other.

Scrolling right - makes the top div scroll right and the bottom div scroll left.
Scrolling left - makes the top div scroll left and the bottom div scroll right.

Should I use jQuery to do this? If anyone can put together a rough example that would be great. mahalo!

Comment: What you did try so far?

Comment: I want to do something similar to the menu on this site: http://www.blacknegative.com at the bottom there is a menu that scrolls 2 different directions. any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

### [jQuery Mousewheel Plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/)

Since you didn't include enough code, I can't help you much. But the best I can do is point you in the right direction. Here's a jQuery [Mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/) library and it should help you get started. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ali, I am going to check it out. I will add my code soon. I was hoping it would be something simple.

Comment: i found this pre-made plugin http://darsa.in/sly/examples/horizontal.html all i need to do is make it scroll 2 divs in opposite directions